# css selector for visible only first section content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JavaScript toggle so T need to tried to collapse all sections on load by default - by inserting

```
ul.section-content{
  display:none;
}
```

and it is working. But when I tried to hide `first-child` or not `first-child` it is not working.

```css
.cscr .csec .section ul:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cscr">
  <ul class="csec">
    <li class="section">
      <div class="section-header">
        <div class="section-left">
          <h5>section01</h5>
          <p>hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-meta">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="section-content">  
        <li class="course-item">
          <h1>lesson01</h1>
        </li>
      </ul>                        
    </li>

    <li class="section">
      <div class="section-header">
        <div class="section-left">
          <h5>section02</h5>
          <p>hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-meta">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="section-content">           /* to hide this */
        <li class="course-item">
          <h1>lesson02</h1>
        </li>
      </ul>                             /* to hide this */
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

second case:
and how to display only first and not others with help of not-first-child

[screenshot of what is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EtnS.jpg)

Comment: yes the first ul ( not the first li )

Comment: its a php loop code. i have taken out the html to make this work .  all ul's have same class

Comment: this is the li loop code. 
<!-- begin snippet:  -->

<li<?php $section->main_class();?> id="section-<?php echo $section->get_slug(); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $section->get_slug(); ?>" data-section-id="<?php echo $section->get_id();?>">

<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOOXOv. Change the CSS properties to whatever you want.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you and please post this as answer so i can mark it right. @psinaught

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOOXOv. Change the CSS properties to whatever you want.

Here you are selecting all sections except the first one and then selecting `ul` inside them.